# Center bootstrap navbar links

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a bootstrap navbar. But I am unable to center all the links to the middle.

I have tried

```
.navbar-nav {
    float: none;
    /*float: none !important;*/
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And My Example [Codepen](http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/BzvYyR) When click on the link you can see links still float left.

> **Question** how is it possible to center the links to middle of page with
>   bootstrap and css

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 40px 0;    
    background-color: #222222;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {

    .navbar-default {
        background: none;
        border: none;
    }

    .navbar-nav {
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
  }

    .navbar:after {
        margin: none;
        content: " ";
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        height: 7px;
        background: #222 !important;
        width: 100%;
    }

    a.navbar-brand {
        transition: color 1s ease, text-shadow 0.3s ease;
        background-color: #222 !important;
        color: #ffffff !important;
        display: inline-block;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: none;
    }

    .navbar-nav > li > a {
        display: inline-block;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: none;
        transition: background 0.1s ease 0.05s, box-shadow 0.1s ease;
        box-shadow: 8px 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        color: #444;
        background: #d9d9d9;
        padding: 15px 45px;
    }

    .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
    .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
        background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #828282 0%, #7d7d7d 19%, #969696 100%);
        box-shadow: 8px 0 25px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        background-color: #969696;
        color: white;    
    }

}

.page-container {
    background: #eee;  
    padding-top: 25px;
    min-height: 380px;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 0px #9C9698, 12px 12px 0px #6B6768;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `float:left` to display:inline-block in `.navbar-nav>li`

for example

```
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The work demo: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/ionurboz/pen/zByRoQ)

```
.navbar-nav{
  text-align:center;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: If I add it in my media it does not work? But works out side need it to work in media

Comment: It Covers all Query... If you want, after the @media add original codes for the original floats.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.dropdown-menu li{
      text-align = "center";
}
```